# want to access data from text box in the form which is in another solution in visual studio 2013?

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf

I have two solutions TranferService and Sender. TranferService has WCF service and IISHost to host that service. In Sender solution i have windows forms application. In that form i used button to browse and select file, text box to display selected file path, and another button(Send) to transfer that file through WCF service. But i am unable to access textbox value in the transfer solution. it shows"the name does not exist in the current context".
Code for TransferService

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;
namespace TransferService
{

// NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "TransferService" in both code and config file together.
public class TransferService : ITransferService
{

    public File DownloadDocument()
    {
        File file = new File();
        String path = txtSelectFilePath.Text;
        file.Content = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@path);
        //file.Name = "ImagingDevices.exe";

        return file;
    }
}
}
```

I am getting error on this line

```
String path = txtSelectFilePath.Text;
```

code for form.cs

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Sender
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Browse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {              
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            txtSelectFilePath.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;

        }

    }

    private void Send_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TransferService.TransferServiceClient client = new TransferService.TransferServiceClient();
        TransferService.File file = client.DownloadDocument();
        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\DownloadedFiles\" + file.Name, file.Content);
        MessageBox.Show(file.Name + " is downloaded");
    } 


}
}
```

Code for ITransferService.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;

namespace TransferService
{
// NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "ITransferService" in both code and config file together.
[ServiceContract]
public interface ITransferService
{
    [OperationContract]
    File DownloadDocument();
}

[DataContract]
public class File
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public byte[] Content { get; set; }

}
}
```

Thanx a lot in advance..........

Comment: If I understand your question correctly: Simply you can't.

Comment: I think is better to add a string argument to DownloadDocument(string path) and pass the path when you call it

Comment: tysm for your reply...... George sir when i tried to pass argument this error comes:- 'TransferService.TransferService' does not implement interface member 'TransferService.ITransferService.DownloadDocument()'

Comment: when i created WCF service and implemented that interface it has generated function which doesn't have argument. is it the reason??

Comment: yes, but i think u can overcome this creating a constructor...see my awnser with a code

Answer (score 0):

Then create a constructor to your class that receives a path as string something like this:

```
public class TransferService : ITransferService
{

    private string _path;
    public TransferService(string path) {
        _path  = path
    }

    public File DownloadDocument()
    {
        File file = new File();
        //String path = txtSelectFilePath.Text;
        file.Content = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(_path);
        //file.Name = "ImagingDevices.exe";

        return file;
    }
}
```

and then on form.cs

```
 TransferService.TransferServiceClient client = new TransferService.TransferServiceClient(txtSelectFilePath.Text);
```

Comment: TransferService.File file = client.DownloadDocument(txtSelectFilePath.Text);         when i try this it gives me error like no overload for method DownloadDocument.

Comment: Is it necessary to edit ITransferService.cs this file also...?

Comment: Sorry fixed, no u dont, i create this to implement the interface without need to changet it, but it is up to you to decide